# Listing MySQL JOINS with no index

Tags: mysql, indexes

Is there a way to generate a list of JOINS being performed without indexes in MySQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have available a list of SELECT queries your application performs, just put `log-queries-not-using-indexes` in your *my.cnf*, restart MySQL and execute all the SELECTs. Then read the log file.

Alternatively you can run `EXPLAIN SELECT your_query_using_JOIN` and read the output.